# Watching the football World Cup final in Amsterdam

Tags: netherlands, sports-events, world-cup

Myself and a group of friends are thinking of going over to the Netherlands if they progress to the final. Does anyone know if the large screening of the final will take place like in 2010 against Spain?

Also is there a cost to get into the square or is a free event?

Comment: or just hop into a cafe with a tv screen :)

Comment: But now the Dutch is out from the final

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**<s>As of now it is not yet *officially* confirmed.</s>**

Thus far mayor of Amsterdam has not allowed quarter-finals nor semi-finals, as matches with Dutch participation start at 22:00 (10pm) and can end as late as 01:00 (1am), which is too late according to Amsterdam's bureaucrats. So one thing for sure, you will *not* be able to watch the semi-final on the big screen at Museumplein.

> **Outdoor screens**
>
> Meanwhile, the Netherlands is gearing up for the match, although big
>   screens showing the match will be hard to find in Amsterdam.
>
> The one on the Museumplein has been removed and will not return unless
>   Oranje reaches the final, and other borough councils have refused to
>   licence outdoor screens. Supporters will have to head for the
>   Arenapark.  *([source](http://www.dutchnews.nl/news/archives/2014/07/dutch_national_football_team_c.php))*

[Arenapark](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arena+Park/@52.311876,4.94225,17z/) is a park by the Bijlmer ArenA, you can get there from the center by metro.

As for the finals, there is no official decision yet. [City hall's official page about World Cup *(in Dutch)*](http://www.amsterdam.nl/toerisme-vrije-tijd/evenementen/wk-2014/) only mentions semi-finals for now. On the other hand the mayor has mentioned in a TV interview that it might be possible to have finals on Museumplein.

[Museumplein](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Museumplein/@52.3573264,4.881469,17z/) is in the city center. For the past matches the location had 3 screens. Entry is free, however you're not allowed to consume alcohol other than bought there.

---

**UPDATE:** As the Netherlands didn't make the final, [it is now  **official**.](http://www.amsterdam.nl/toerisme-vrije-tijd/evenementen/wk-2014/)

> De troostfinale, op zaterdag 12 juli, en de finale, op zondag 13 juli,
>   zullen niet op een groot scherm te zien zijn op het Museumplein.

translation:

> The consolation final, on Saturday, July 12th, and the final on
>   Sunday, July 13th, **will not be seen on the big screen at the Museumplein**.

Also, no mention of Arenapark at all, which might suggest it won't be shown there either.

Answer (score 6):

Details are yet to be confirmed but the main location would be the Museumplein, south of the centre. See [1](http://blog.hostelbookers.com/travel/eating-and-drinking/watch-world-cup-amsterdam/) and [2](http://www.amsterdam.nl/ondernemen/branches/horeca/feestelijk-wk/)

If public viewing is allowed here or elsewhere, the municipality requires that access must be free of charge and sufficient water should be available for free.

Comment: Do you know if you need tickets or do you just turn up

Comment: @Lt_Shade I assume it's free, for different reasons, but I have never watched a football game in Amsterdam itself.

Comment: @Dirty-flow Indeed! Copy-paste fail…

Comment: Linked articles don't provide accurate information about semi-finals though. Fact is *„The one on the Museumplein has been removed and will not return unless Oranje reaches the final, and other borough councils have refused to licence outdoor screens. Supporters will have to head for the Arenapark.”*

Comment: @vartec The municipality website does in fact imply something like that (missed it when I posted the link) but the question is about the final anyway. I don't think a final decision will be made before it is known whether the Dutch team does make it to the final.

Comment: @Lt_Shade Upon rereading the official webpage, I found more info on access. It should in any case be free, that much is known.

Comment: @Relaxed Free doesn't necessarily mean unticketed. For example (totally different event, I know), various Olympic Torch Relay events in the UK in 2012 required people to get tickets in advance, even though tickets were free. Presumably, this was to control the number of people trying to enter the venue.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, which is why I wrote “free of charge” in my answer as it is precisely what “gratis” means.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could go to Groningen, in the north of The Netherlands.

The past couple of matches have been shown on large screens on the market square ("Grote Markt"). The semi-final against Argentina will be shown there as well, so there's a good chance the final will be shown as well.

[Here's a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc_o56rvpEg) of the penalty in the match against Mexico, as experienced on the Grote Markt.